# Dictionary to a txt file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying  to write a dictionary to a .txt file. I haven't found an efficient way to add multiple values for keys to a text doc.

```
players = {}
def save_roster(players):
    with open("Team Roster.txt", "wt") as out_file:
        for k, v in players.items():
            out_file.write(str(k) + ', ' + str(v) + '\n\n')
    display_menu()
```

I have a dictionary that has multiple values for the key. This part of the program leave me with:

```
Bryce, <__main__.Roster object at 0x00000167D6DB6550>
```

Where the out put i am aiming for is:

```
Bryce, 23, third, 23
```

Comment: What does the Roster object look like?  I think you might need to implement the `__repr__` method for the class.

Comment: def __init__(self, name, age, position, jersey):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.position = position
        self.jersey = jersey

    def setname(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setage(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def settype(self, position):
        self.position = position

    def setowner(self, jersey):
        self.jersey = jersey

    def getname(self):
        return self.name

    def getage(self):
        return self.age

Comment: Did you try implementing the __repr__ method in the class?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional details when requested, don't put code in the comments.

Comment: Yes, It did help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't inherently understand how to print an object. You need to define the `__str__` method in order to tell python how to represent your object as a string; otherwise it will default to the representation you're getting. In your case, I might go with something like

```
def __str__(self):
   return str(self.position)+", "+str(self.jersey)
```

or whichever attributes you want to print.

And to read the data back in from the text file:

```
with open("Team Roster.txt", "r") as in_file:
   for line in in_file:
      player = Roster(*(line.split(", "))
      #do something with player, like store it in a list
```

Assuming `Roster.__init__()` is set up appropriately, i.e. a Roster object is initialized by passing in the parameters in each line of the file in order.

Comment: So how would i reverse the process after i set the format to the desired format? To pull the same information back into the program from the text file i just created?

Comment: @ActionDubs A different question, but I edited in an answer to it.

Comment: I know this is a different question and i thank you for answering it here as well. i keep getting: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable